# Cleaning emails in a dataframe with .apply() - dataframe not being updated

Tags: python, pandas

My apply function is not doing anything to the data.

I am trying to insert `@` into emails that are missing this character.

For example to convert `joebloggsgmail.com` to `joebloggs@gmail.com` I will concatenate `joebloggs + @ + gmail.com`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':'foobargmail.com barfoo@gmail.com hellotheregmail.com myemailhotmail.com'.split(),
                      'col2':'make a data frame'.split()})

print(df)

                 email   col2
0      foobargmail.com   make
1     barfoo@gmail.com      a
2  hellotheregmail.com   data
3  myemailhotmeail.com  frame


domains =  ['gmail.com hotmail.com yahoo.com hotmail.co.uk']
```

In the below function I check if the character before the domain is `@` and if not, insert it.

```
def cleaning(row):

    # for each domain in the list
    for d in domains:

        # if the domain is in the email
        if d in row:

            # the character before the domain is not equal to @
            if row[-len(d)-1] != '@':

                # concatenate name + @ + domain
                row = row[:-len(d)] + '@' + row[-len(d):]

    return row
```

My expected result is:

```
                  email   col2
0      foobar@gmail.com   make
1      barfoo@gmail.com      a
2  hello@theregmail.com   data
3  myemail@hotmeail.com  frame
```

I would really like to keep it as an `.apply()` function because I am trying to learn how to use these. However if I shouldn't be doing this or if there is a much better way then I'm all ears.

*edit:* @Tomaz Gandor spotted a mistake in my code. It works after changing it. Thanks to everybody else for their suggestions. I wanted to keep it in an apply function as it is going to be part of a larger apply function.

Comment: You have just 1 string in the domains list, probably you wanted no square brackets, and a `split()`. Also - the row is not a string, you need row['email'] everywhere.

Comment: 1 string in the domains list.. just noticed. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TomaszGandor I actually consider this the answer as you spotted my mistake. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex with values before joined emails, `@` with `?` for optional character to new `DataFrame` and then concat together by [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
domains =  ['gmail.com hotmail.com yahoo.com hotmail.co.uk']

pat = '|'.join(domains[0].split())
df1 = df['email'].str.extract(f'(\w*)[@]*({pat})')
print (df1)
            0            1
0      foobar    gmail.com
1      barfoo    gmail.com
2  hellothere    gmail.com
3     myemail  hotmail.com

df['email'] = df1[0].str.cat(df1[1], '@')
print (df)
                  email   col2
0      foobar@gmail.com   make
1      barfoo@gmail.com      a
2  hellothere@gmail.com   data
3   myemail@hotmail.com  frame
```

Comment: I like your regex logic.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Thank you, for you too plus1

Answer (score 2):

using `re.findall`

```
domains = '|'.join(domains[0].split())
## 'gmail.com|hotmail.com|yahoo.com|hotmail.co.uk'


df.email.apply(lambda x: re.findall('(\w*)(gmail.com|hotmail.com|yahoo.com|hotmail.co.uk)',x)[0][0] +'@'+ re.findall('(\w*)(gmail.com|hotmail.com|yahoo.com|hotmail.co.uk)',x)[0][1] if '@' not in x else x )
```

**Output**

```
0        foobar@gmail.com
1        barfoo@gmail.com
2    hellothere@gmail.com
3     myemail@hotmail.com
Name: email, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) as:

```
pattern = '|'.join(domains[0].split())
df['email'] = (df['email'].str.split(pattern).str[0].str.replace('@','')+'@'+
               df['email'].str.extract('('+pattern+')', expand=False))

print(df)
                  email   col2
0      foobar@gmail.com   make
1      barfoo@gmail.com      a
2  hellothere@gmail.com   data
3   myemail@hotmail.com  frame
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def cleaning(row):
    # for each domain in the list
    for d in domains:
        # if the domain is in the email
        if d in row:
            # the character before the domain is not equal to @
            if row[-len(d)-1] != '@':
                # concatenate name + @ + domain
                row = row[:-len(d)] + '@' + row[-len(d):]
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame({'email':'foobargmail.com barfoo@gmail.com hellotheregmail.com myemailhotmail.com'.split(), 'col2':'make a data frame'.split()})
domains =  ['gmail.com hotmail.com yahoo.com hotmail.co.uk']
domains = domains[0].split() # added this line of code
df['email'] = df.email.apply(cleaning)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                  email   col2
0      foobar@gmail.com   make
1      barfoo@gmail.com      a
2  hellothere@gmail.com   data
3   myemail@hotmail.com  frame
```